# owl carousel showing faded duplicate text on Chrome 40

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, owl-carousel

Currently on Chrome version 40 the carousel is showing duplicate text on slides that slide in (not the slides that are showing on load), this made me think that it was because I had lazyload set to true but that didn't help when I altered that.

Here's the website that it's set up in, scroll down the home page to see the carousel: http://autoplay.web.aptest.co.nz/Default.aspx

here's a screen shot.
[image: carousel error on chrome 40]

Any more questions, please post up.